Why do words like 'irregardless' and 'conversate' form?
I have seen both of these words in my daily life. However, they shadow words which already convey the same meaning: 'irregardless' is the same as 'regardless;' 'conversate' (more commonly 'conversating') is the same as 'converse' ('conversing'). Why do these seemingly incorrect words form?
They always seem to follow the form of the original word. It is understandable that one might say conversating, since the noun form of converse is conversation; but why does this sort of backwards word formation happen?
Another good, although slightly different example is 'postfix.' It seems to have shifted to fit modern word definitions—one could expect 'post-' to be a better opposite to 'pre-' than 'suf-' (really 'sub').
Extra bonus question: should these new creations be considered valid words? Do they belong in a dictionary?

@minseong  take a look at IMDB  "Idiocracy"

I'll refer you to George Carlin, "Consider how stupid the average person is, ...."

It hadn't occurred to me that "postfix" has a meaning very similar to "suffix" until you pointed it out just now, but I find it interesting that in computing science we would never say, as an opposite to "prefix notation" (+ 2 3), "suffix notation," but only "postfix notation" (2 3 +).

See To the distress of wordists, a dictionary has confirmed the lexical veracity of 'irregardless'. "I use it whenever I can primarily because it gives people the massive pip with ever an outcry and miffled disgruntlement"

@minseong "Ideocracy" suggests "rule by idiots", which isn't the same as "idiocy"

@SimonCrase I think "ideocracy" would be "rule by ideas," whatever that means.

Conversate is an example of back-formation. Given a noun on -ation, it is very difficult if possible at all to formalize the rules to get back to the base form. Thus we have educate > education but found > foundation. In cases like conversation, the derived form (conversation) is more frequent than the base form (converse), and is therefore more accessible to speakers. When a speaker has to come up with a word for "performing a conversation", she can either get it from memory (converse) or try to form it based on the result noun conversation, which may  be easier depending how much more accessible it is. However, because conversation can in principle be derived from both converse and conversate, errors can occur, especially under pressure. Once such errors occur frequently enough, this can lead to a snowball effect, whereby the fact that speakers have already heard others use conversate contributes to their own use of it.
Irregardless is of a slightly different kind, as it is probably a portmanteau of irrespective and regardless (another, compatible, explanation is that ir- strengthens the negation of -less). One might note that the meaning of regardless is not entirely the same as without regard to the foregoing. Thus, regardless is not entirely semantically transparent, which may contribute to its occurrence in a portmanteau. In a way, this links regardless to conversation, which is likewise somewhat opaque semantically (is it converse + -ate + -ion or converse + -ation? – -ation is diachronically but not synchronically equivalent to -ate + -ion).
Whether these forms should be considered valid, and whether they belong in a dictionary, depends on where you position yourself on the descriptive–prescriptive divide.

… and also on how widespread they are. Irregardless and probably conversate are certainly widespread enough that they belong in a dictionary, if nothing else as non-standard forms directing the reader to the more widely accepted forms. The suffix -en is productively used to form verbs from monosyllabic adjectives terms ending in an obstruent, but you sometimes hear people use it analogically with other bases (especially colour terms), like greenen or orangen; these I would not expect to find in a dictionary, since they’re quite rare and idiosyncratic.

They are both non standard. You don't need conversate when you have converse. Generally, they'd be used by the unschooled, which is fine, but that's the truth. They are sociolectally definable in that sense.

That's funny I though irregardless was the result of double-negation.

@Joshua that’s another possible story, yes. Could be both as well.

By comparison, conservate has been around since at least the 19th century, which might be an additional reason why speakers use conversate by analogy?

@gerrit for sure! I have added your and Joshua's points to the answer.

@JanusBahsJacquet If being widespread is the only criteria for a word to be added to a dictionary, the English language is in trouble.

@Mentalist Dictionaries are tools meant to describe the vocabulary of a language as it is used by its community of speakers. Widespread usage is pretty much the criterion for dictionary inclusion, yes, and that goes not just for English, but for any language. The only exception is prescriptive dictionaries (e.g., spelling dictionaries for officially codified orthographies), but English doesn’t really have any of those since it has no officially codified standards; the closest is style guides, which are a very different thing.

btw "commentate" is notably different than "comment".

@Mentalist By that kind of criterion, the English language has been "in trouble" since it started. (This is not surprising, given that it "lurks in dark alleys....")

It's just the normal evolution of Human speech.
Nobody ever invented a spoken language, Esperanto notwithstanding. Every language is a perversion of another language.
...Which changes. When I was a kid, "party" was not a verb. It would have sounded very strange.
Now, people say "these ones" and omit infinitives ("Kitty wants petted.").
You can't correct them; all you can do is shrug.

‘When I was a kid, "party" was not a verb’… Well, we have academic works and official government records using "party" as a verb going back at least as far as the 1580s, so you appear to be far older than expected.

No, i'm 44. I'm just not very literate.

the expressions "these ones" and "those ones" is 100% standard in English. Every language is a perversion of another? that's a bit harsh.

Without trying to read too deeply into it, "kitty wants petted" might be specific to the internet communities you hang out in.

...Or to (esp. northern) Appalachian English (e.g., Pittsburghese), with some evidence of this usage gaining traction in the Midwest and even Montana.  (More details.)

@JirkaHanika: Indeed, it was not until I lived with two people who grew up near Pittsburgh that I realized "I'm doing laundry, do you have anything that needs washed" was a thing. But it is common in that area and you get used to it very quickly.

When writing my answer, I was specifically thinking about two people from Pennsylvania , one from Pittsburgh. "we-uns, you-uns, jag yer wires," etc.
